# How to list directories, sub-directories and all files in php

Tags: php, file, directory, subdirectory

I want to be able to list all the directories, subdirectories and files in the "./" folder ie the project folder called fileSystem which contains this php file scanDir.php.

You can view the directory system I've got here:
[image]

At the minute it will only return the subdirectory folders/files in the root of the mkdir directory but not any folders inside that subdirectory.

How do I modify the code so that it demonstrates all the files, directories, subdirectories and their files and subdirectories within the fileSystem folder given that the php file being run is called scanDir.php and the code for that is provided below.
Here is the php code:

```
 $path = "./";

 if(is_dir($path))

{
    $dir_handle = opendir($path);

    //extra check to see if it's a directory handle.
    //loop round one directory and read all it's content.
    //readdir takes optional parameter of directory handle.
    //if you only scan one single directory then no need to passs in argument.
    //if you are then going to scan into sub-directories the argument needs 
    //to be passed into readdir.
    while (($dir = readdir($dir_handle))!== false) 
    {
    if(is_dir($dir))
    {
    echo "is dir: " . $dir . "<br>"; 


    if($dir == "mkdir") 
        {
        $sub_dir_handle = opendir($dir);
        while(($sub_dir = readdir($sub_dir_handle))!== false)
            {
            echo "--> --> contents=$sub_dir <br>";
            }
    }



    }    
        elseif(is_file($dir)) 
         {
            echo "is file: " . $dir . "<br>"  ;
        }
    }
closedir($dir_handle); //will close the automatically open dir.
}

else {

    echo "is not a directory";
}
```

Comment: Use `scandir` to list all folders and files, then use `is_file` the item is file, else it's folder and repeat the process. I'll do answer with the full code soon

Comment: thank you, I look forward to seeing your full code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to see all stuff in the directory and `is_file` to check if the item is file or next directory, if it is directory, repeat the same thing over and over.

So, this is completely new code.

```
function listIt($path) {
$items = scandir($path);

foreach($items as $item) {

    // Ignore the . and .. folders
    if($item != "." AND $item != "..") {
        if (is_file($path . $item)) {
            // this is the file
            echo "-> " . $item . "<br>";
        } else {
            // this is the directory

            // do the list it again!
            echo "---> " . $item;
            echo "<div style='padding-left: 10px'>";
            listIt($path . $item . "/");
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
  }
}

echo "<div style='padding-left: 10px'>";
listIt("/");
echo "</div>";
```

[You can see the live demo here in my webserver, btw, I will keep this link just for a second](http://developer.symbiant.cz/stackoverflow/haider123.php)

When you see the "->" it's an file and "-->" is a directory

The pure code with no HTML:

```
function listIt($path) {
$items = scandir($path);

foreach($items as $item) {
    // Ignore the . and .. folders
    if($item != "." AND $item != "..") {
        if (is_file($path . $item)) {
            // this is the file
            // Code for file
        } else {
            // this is the directory
            // do the list it again!
            // Code for directory
            listIt($path . $item . "/");
        }
    }
  }
}

listIt("/");
```

*the demo can take a while to load, it's a lot of items.*

Comment: thank you and if i wanted to display a way to go up a directory or down into a directory would I remove the "." and ".." code from the if statement or is going up or down into a directory, hiding and displaying directories the preserve of javascript?

Comment: Well yea, if you noticed, all the directories are in the `div` block, so just identify them by "id" and use for the example jQuery's functions `.hide()` and `.show()`

Comment: what does the line at the end of the code listIt("/"); do?

Comment: I'm running the code on my mac and it displays everything on my mac, how do I limit it so it only displays the file directories in the scandir1.php

Comment: Yea you have to set the full path, that's the "/" just enter your path from the root here :)

Comment: I've added the show/hide buttons, they look weird but... They work :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92586/discussion-between-tomas-aresak-malcanek-and-abdullah-haider).

Comment: thank you I've made that change to just the users folder (as you can see in the image) but I can't see any files inside it, how would I do that?

Comment: I've started messaging in the chat discussion room

Comment: Make sure the path always ends with the slash "/"! or it will look like `cusersmedesktop`, which is invalid path instead of `c/users/me/desktop/`

Answer (score 4):

There are some powerful builtin functions for PHP to find files and folders, personally I like the `recursiveIterator` family of classes.

```
$startfolder=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$files=array();


foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $startfolder, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST ) as $file => $info ) {
    if( $info->isFile() && $info->isReadable() ){
        $files[]=array('filename'=>$info->getFilename(),'path'=>realpath( $info->getPathname() ) );
    }
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($files,true),'</pre>';
```

Comment: where would I add this within the current code? or is this a new set to create in a seperate file?

Comment: is there a way to do it while modifying the existing code?

Comment: oh and is it possible to do it from the fileSystem folder rather than the server root? ie loop through the subdirectories and directories of the fileSystem folder rather than ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] how would i do that?

Comment: Yes, this will work on the filesystem and not just within the document root